# HTML validation error document type does not allow element "hr"

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I want to show a list of articles such as image, title, hr, and date using a `UL`. I am getting validation error when I test them on https://validator.w3.org/ when testing the actual website.

Below is the dummy schema & is almost an exact copy of the actual HTML. When I test the below HTML as code it doesn't generate errors, but when I test URL it generates an error as shown below:

> document type does not allow element "hr" here; missing one of
> "object", "applet", "map", "iframe", "button", "ins", "del" start-tag
>
> ```
>                                     <hr />
> ```
>
> The mentioned element is not allowed to appear in the context in which
> you've placed it; the other mentioned elements are the only ones that
> are both allowed there and can contain the element mentioned. This
> might mean that you need a containing element, or possibly that you've
> forgotten to close a previous element.
>
> One possible cause for this message is that you have attempted to put
> a block-level element (such as "`<p>`" or "`<table>`") inside an inline
> element (such as "`<a>`", "`<span>`", or "`<font>`").

**HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="listwrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixum.com/100/100/nature/1" alt="image" />
      <span>Headline</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
          <hr/>
    </li>
       
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixum.com/100/100/nature/2" alt="image"/>
      <span>Headline</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
          <hr/>
    </li>
 
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixum.com/100/100/nature/3" alt="image"/>
      <span>Headline</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
          <hr/>
    </li>
 
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixum.com/100/100/nature/4" alt="image"/>
      <span>Headline</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
          <hr/>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried replacing html with div and span, but I kept generating the same error.

Comment: `<hr/>` shouldn't be used in `<ul>` and `<li>`. Pretty sure thats what the error is saying.

Comment: That is what is causing the error by replacing it with span div also generate same error

Comment: Instead of an <hr>, why not just set some extra margin/padding for the <li>'s in CSS and add border-bottom?

Comment: Like Hans says in the answer, you can't put a block element in an inline element. But since you have solved the problem in this example here (this example _does_ validate as XHTML), why don't you simply apply the same solution to the actual webpage?

Comment: Also, why are you using XHTML anyway? The rest of your question only speaks of HTML and there seems to be no requirement for XHTML whatsoever.

Comment: The code posted is valid (though of poor quality), so the question does not present a real problem. You should include the code that does *not* validate (or avoid the problem by using a bottom border for the `li` elements, with CSS, since the use of `hr` is neither logical nor practical here).

Answer (score -1):

The [w3schools](http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp) page about HR says it's used for creating a break in the content for switching topic or such. So i guess you "can't" use it in inline elements. I would do like @stckrboy suggested in the comments, and create the line with CSS instead.